# How can i get the nearest next time in array using moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to find the nearest next time to a given time, I got [this code from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643665/how-to-find-the-closest-time-to-the-given-time-using-moment) but I am unable to get the desired result

```js
// Current time in millis
const now = +moment('10:07', 'HH:mm').format('x');
// List of times
const times = ["10:00", "10:18", "23:30", "12:00"];
// Times in milliseconds
const timesInMillis = times.map(t => +moment(t, "HH:mm").format("x"));

function closestTime(arr, time) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return Math.abs(curr - time) < Math.abs(prev - time) ? curr : prev;
  });
}

const closest = moment(closestTime(timesInMillis, now)).format('HH:mm');

// closest is 10:00 but i want the next time 10:18
console.log(closest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the closest time to the given time using moment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643665/how-to-find-the-closest-time-to-the-given-time-using-moment)

Comment: you copied the code from a question and ignored it's answer. also, you don't tell what result you desire and what's not working for you.

Comment: @MarkusDresch The answer did not work for OP because it was the _the nearest time, before the given time but under the same minute_ whatever they meant - also far to unnecessary complex for THIS question

Comment: @MarkusDresch _closest is 10:00 but i want the next time 10:18_

Comment: @mplungjan alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for moment at all

24-hour time is sortable and directly comparable

```js
const times = ["10:00", "10:18", "23:30", "12:00"].sort();

const getClosest = targetTime => times.find(time => time >= targetTime) || "N/A";

console.log(getClosest("10:07"));

console.log(getClosest("11:30"));

console.log(getClosest("13:30"));

console.log(getClosest("23:40")); // not available in array
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mplungjan .. Javascript is simply superb..